# Not all updates can be installed

Tags: update-manager, ubuntu-mate

Every time I run software updater, Upgrade manager says not all updates can be installed and wants me to do a partial upgrade.

I have tried sudo dpkg --configure -a and sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install.

Sometimes it will say the software is up to date.

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                             
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                         
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                     
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                        
Hit:2 https://phoenixnap.dl.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all InRelease                      
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                      
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease        
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sane-project/sane-git/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done                                                 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
18 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ant ant-optional antlr3 app-install-data aspectj autokey-common bnd brainparty-data casper catdoc cube2
  default-jdk default-jdk-doc default-jdk-headless efibootmgr finalrd fonts-dejavu fonts-linuxlibertine
  fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic gnome-software-common grub-efi-amd64-bin isolinux java-wrappers
  javahelp2 javascript-common junit junit-doc junit4 junit4-doc k3b-data kactivities-bin kactivitymanagerd
  kate5-data ktexteditor-data ktexteditor-katepart libactivation-java libaldmb1 libalien-sdl-perl
  liballegro4.4 libalut0 libantlr-java libantlr3-runtime-java libantlr4-runtime-java libaopalliance-java
  libapache-pom-java libappstream-glib8 libapr1 libaprutil1 libargs4j-java libasm-java libaspectj-java
  libatinject-jsr330-api-java libaudclient2 libavalon-framework-java libavdevice57 libbeansbinding-java
  libbindex-java libboost-signals1.65.1 libbsh-java libbyte-buddy-java libbytelist-java libcapture-tiny-perl
  libcdi-api-java libcglib-java libclass-inspector-perl libcodemodel-java libcommons-beanutils-java
  libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-compress-java
  libcommons-digester-java libcommons-io-java libcommons-lang-java libcommons-lang3-java
  libcommons-logging-java libcommons-net-java libcommons-parent-java libcompress-bzip2-perl libdom4j-java
  libdtd-parser-java libdumb1 libeclipselink-java libeditorconfig0 libel-api-java libenet7 libepub0
  libequinox-osgi-java libexcalibur-logkit-java libfastinfoset-java libfelix-framework-java
  libfelix-gogo-runtime-java libfelix-main-java libfelix-osgi-obr-java libfelix-resolver-java
  libfile-sharedir-perl libfile-which-perl libfluidsynth1 libfreemarker-java
  libgeronimo-annotation-1.3-spec-java libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java
  libgeronimo-j2ee-connector-1.5-spec-java libgeronimo-jms-1.1-spec-java libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java
  libgeronimo-validation-1.1-spec-java libgexiv2-2 libgit2-26 libgspell-1-1 libgspell-1-common libguava-java
  libguice-java libhamcrest-java libhamcrest-java-doc libhawtjni-runtime-java libhidapi-libusb0
  libhtml5parser-java libhttp-parser2.7.1 libhttpclient-java libhttpcore-java libicu4j-4.4-java libini4j-java
  libistack-commons-java libjansi-java libjansi-native-java libjavaewah-java libjaxb-api-java libjaxb-java
  libjaxen-java libjaxrs-api-java libjcodings-java libjcommander-java libjemmy2-java libjgit-java libjna-java
  libjna-jni libjna-platform-java libjnlp-servlet-java libjoda-time-java libjpa-2.1-spec-java libjs-jquery
  libjs-underscore libjsch-agent-proxy-java libjsch-java libjson-simple-java libjsonp-java libjsoup-java
  libjsp-api-java libjsr305-java libjvyamlb-java libjzlib-java libk3b7 libk3b7-extracodecs libkf5activities5
  libkf5calendarevents5 libkf5cddb-data libkf5cddb5 libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data
  libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5itemmodels5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5notifyconfig-data
  libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libkf5syntaxhighlighting-data libkf5syntaxhighlighting5
  libkf5texteditor5 libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore libkf5threadweaver5 libkxml2-java libllvm9
  libllvm9:i386 liblog4j1.2-java liblucene3-contrib-java liblucene3-java libmail-java
  libmaven-file-management-java libmaven-parent-java libmaven-resolver-java libmaven-shared-io-java
  libmaven-shared-utils-java libmaven3-core-java libmikmod3 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmodplug1 libmp3splt
  libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libnb-absolutelayout-java libnb-javaparser-java libnb-org-openide-util-java
  libnb-org-openide-util-lookup-java libode6 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0 libopenhmd0
  libosgi-annotation-java libosgi-compendium-java libosgi-core-java libphysfs1 libplank-common libplank1
  libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-cipher-java libplexus-classworlds-java
  libplexus-component-annotations-java libplexus-interpolation-java libplexus-io-java
  libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java libplexus-utils-java libplexus-utils2-java libpoppler-qt5-1
  libqscintilla2-qt5-13 libqscintilla2-qt5-l10n libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libquicktime2 libregexp-java
  librelaxng-datatype-java librngom-java libsdl-gfx1.2-5 libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-net1.2 libsdl-pango1
  libsdl-perl libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libsdo-api-java
  libsequence-library-java libserf-1-1 libservlet-api-java libservlet3.1-java libsimple-validation-java
  libsisu-guice-java libsisu-inject-java libsisu-ioc-java libsisu-plexus-java libslf4j-java libsnappy-java
  libsnappy-jni libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base libsox3 libsqljet-java libstax-ex-java libstreambuffer-java
  libstringtemplate-java libstringtemplate4-java libsvn-java libsvn1 libsvnclientadapter-java libsvnkit-java
  libswing-layout-java libswingx-java libsystemback libtie-simple-perl libtrilead-ssh2-java libtxw2-java
  libuchardet0 libwagon-http-java libwagon-provider-api-java libwebsocket-api-java libws-commons-util-java
  libxcb-composite0 libxcb-damage0 libxmmsclient6 libxnvctrl0 libxsom-java libxz-java libyaml-snake-java
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-42 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-45 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-47
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-48 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-51 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-52
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-53 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-54 localechooser-data lupin-casper
  open-invaders-data openjdk-11-doc openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-jdk-headless pingus-data plasma-framework
  python-pyinotify python-simplejson qml-module-org-kde-kconfig qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols
  qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts
  qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets shotwell-common sox syslinux-utils systemback-cli systemback-efiboot-amd64
  systemback-locales systemback-scheduler testng timgm6mb-soundfont transcode transcode-doc ttf-dejavu-core
  ttf-ubuntu-font-family twolame user-setup
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-60 linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsane libsane:i386 libsane-common libsane1 libsane1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apport-gtk libsasl2-2 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 python3-apport python3-problem-report
13 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 73.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 349 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-problem-report all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21 [10.3 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-apport all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21 [82.3 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apport all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21 [125 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic amd64 5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1 [14.3 MB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apport-gtk all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21 [9,700 B]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsasl2-modules-db amd64 2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3 [15.0 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 libsasl2-modules-db i386 2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3 [15.8 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 libsasl2-2 i386 2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3 [52.8 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsasl2-2 amd64 2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3 [49.2 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsasl2-modules amd64 2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3 [48.9 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 libsasl2-modules i386 2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3 [52.6 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic amd64 5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1 [8,976 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic amd64 5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1 [38.0 MB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-generic-hwe-18.04 amd64 5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55 [1,940 B]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 amd64 5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55 [2,704 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-60 all 5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1 [11.0 MB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic amd64 5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1 [1,160 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 amd64 5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55 [2,576 B]
Fetched 73.9 MB in 41s (1,783 kB/s)                                                                            
(Reading database ... 470604 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-python3-problem-report_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-problem-report (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21) over (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.20) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-python3-apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21) over (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.20) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21_all.deb ...
Unpacking apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21) over (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.20) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-apport-gtk_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21_all.deb ...
Unpacking apport-gtk (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21) over (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.20) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-libsasl2-modules-db_2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libsasl2-modules-db:i386 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) over (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libsasl2-modules-db_2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules-db:i386 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) over (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libsasl2-2_2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Unpacking libsasl2-2:i386 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) over (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-libsasl2-2_2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) over (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-libsasl2-modules_2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libsasl2-modules:i386 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) over (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-libsasl2-modules_2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules:i386 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) over (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../10-linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic_5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../11-linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic_5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../12-linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic_5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-linux-generic-hwe-18.04_5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55) over (5.4.0.58.64~18.04.53) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04_5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 (5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55) over (5.4.0.58.64~18.04.53) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-60.
Preparing to unpack .../15-linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-60_5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-60 (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../16-linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic_5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04_5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 (5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55) over (5.4.0.58.64~18.04.53) ...
Setting up linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-60 (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules-db:i386 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libsasl2-2:i386 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
Setting up python3-problem-report (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules:i386 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-3ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 (5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
I: /vmlinuz is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-60-generic
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-60-generic
Setting up python3-apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21) ...
Setting up linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
Setting up apport (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21) ...
apport-autoreport.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Setting up linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 (5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55) ...
Setting up apport-gtk (2.20.9-0ubuntu7.21) ...
Setting up linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (5.4.0.60.67~18.04.55) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.43) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic (5.4.0-60.67~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-60-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-60-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-60-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (20.04) on /dev/sda2
done
```

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: @user535733 I have updated my question.

Comment: That's a suspiciously large number of orphaned packages eligible for autoremoval. Have you looked into that?

Comment: user535733@ I ran all the commands offered here and update manager is now working correctly. sudo apt upgrade no longer shows any orphaned packages. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

Comment: dist-upgrade can break your system, because it can remove packages. Without further explanation I don't think this is an appropriate answer.